# How can I use :before property to create a square before a span

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to create a square in front of a span. Something like this [image](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/174650/ee51cf32147fa63cc5eb177c08cf6038).

[image]

But I am not successful in creating this with `span:before` property. Is it possible to create with this? If yes then can someone please tell me how can I do this?

I have created this with simple CSS . Here is my code

**HTML:**

```
<div id="five_day_table">
    <h3>Annual Cleaning Schedule</h3>
    <div class="r-cl"><span></span>Forecasted Rain Clean</div>
    <div class="m-cl"><span></span>Forecasted Manual Clean</div>
    <div class="cm-cl"><span></span>Completed Manual Clean</div>
    <div class="d-cl"><span></span>Forecasted Dirty Rain</div>
</div>
```

and **CSS**

```
#five_day_table span {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 1px 3px 0px 0px;
}
.r-cl span
{
 background:  Blue; 
}
.m-cl span
{
 background:  red; 
}
.cm-cl span
{
 background:  green; 
}
.d-cl span
{
 background:  brown; 
}
```

Here is the working link. But I want to use this HTML only.

```
<div id="five_day_table">
    <h3>Annual Cleaning Schedule</h3>
    <span class='one'>Forecasted Rain Clean</span>
    <span class='two'>Forecasted Manual Clean</span>
    <span class='three'>Completed Manual Clean</span>
    <span class='four'>Forecasted Dirty Rain</span>
</div>
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to add `content: ""` for `span:before` to work

```css
#five_day_table span {
  display: block;
  margin: 1px 3px 0px 0px;
}
span:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.one:before {
  background: Blue;
}
.two:before {
  background: red;
}
.three:before {
  background: green;
}
.four:before {
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<div id="five_day_table">
  <h3>Annual Cleaning Schedule</h3>
  <span class='one'>Forecasted Rain Clean</span>
  <span class='two'>Forecasted Manual Clean</span>
  <span class='three'>Completed Manual Clean</span>
  <span class='four'>Forecasted Dirty Rain</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do that by adding "content: '■'; "

```css
#five_day_table span {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 1px 0 0px 0px;
}

#five_day_table span:before {
  content: '■'; 
  margin-right: 2px;
  font-size: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

#five_day_table span:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear:both;
}

span.one:before
{
 color:  Blue; 
}
span.two:before
{
 color:  red; 
}
span.three:before
{
 color:  green; 
}
span.four:before
{
 color:  brown; 
}
```

```html
<div id="five_day_table">
    <h3>Annual Cleaning Schedule</h3>
    <span class='one'>Forecasted Rain Clean</span>
    <span class='two'>Forecasted Manual Clean</span>
    <span class='three'>Completed Manual Clean</span>
    <span class='four'>Forecasted Dirty Rain</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @zlatkoVujicic I have updated my code, with the font size of 25px. You can increase the size by increasing the font size.

Comment: yeh I know,  and it looks more flexible when its done your way

Answer (score 2):

```css
span{
    display:block;
}

#five_day_table span:before {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1px 3px 0px 0px;
    content:"";
}
.one:before
{
 background:  Blue; 
}
.two:before
{
 background:  red; 
}
.three:before
{
 background:  green; 
}
.four:before
{
 background:  brown; 
}
```

```html
<div id="five_day_table">
    <h3>Annual Cleaning Schedule</h3>
    <span class='one'>Forecasted Rain Clean</span>
    <span class='two'>Forecasted Manual Clean</span>
    <span class='three'>Completed Manual Clean</span>
    <span class='four'>Forecasted Dirty Rain</span>
</div>
```

> Just Add `:before` in your old CSS and change the `block` to
>   `inline-block` so that it fits in a line and have a `block` for the
>   whole `span` and rest change the css selectors to `:before` so that is
>   takes its respective color.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

[CodePen Sample](http://codepen.io/zlajaa1/pen/PqqrYa)

What you need to do, is to remove width from span, and change class. Note that `:before` need to have `content: ''` property in order to be shown.

Here's HTML code:

```
<div id="five_day_table">
    <h3>Annual Cleaning Schedule</h3>
    <span class='one'>Forecasted Rain Clean</span>
    <span class='two'>Forecasted Manual Clean</span>
    <span class='three'>Completed Manual Clean</span>
    <span class='four'>Forecasted Dirty Rain</span>
</div>
```

And css:

```
#five_day_table span {
    height: 14px;
    display: block;
    margin: 1px 3px 3px 0px;
}
#five_day_table span:before{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.one:before{
     background:  Blue; 
}
.two:before{
     background:  red; 
}
.three:before{
     background:  green; 
}
.four:before{
     background:  brown; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/4p3632pg/

This should be what you're looking for

```
#five_day_table > span {
    display:block;
}
#five_day_table > span::before {
    content:'';
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 1px 3px 0px 0px;
}
.one::before
{
 background:  Blue; 
}
.two::before
{
 background:  red; 
}
.three::before
{
 background:  green; 
}
.four::before
{
 background:  brown; 
}
```